# How can I delete duplicates from a table based on a location id and name

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

columns are:  Name, Location_Name, Location_ID

I want to check Names and Location_ID, and if there are two that are the same I want to delete/remove that row.

For example: If Name John Fox at location id 4 shows up two or more times I want to just keep one.

After that, I want to count how many people per location.
Location_Name1: 45
Location_Name2: 66
Etc...
The location name and Location Id are related.
[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSt5l.png)

[Code I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWoqG.png)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: The `x` up top should be `cte` and which rows in your screen shot do you actually intend to delete? I don't see any where name and branch key repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code

```
CREATE TABLE People_Location
(
Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Location_Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Location_ID INT NOT NULL,
)

INSERT INTO People_Location
VALUES
('John Fox', 'Moon', 4),
('John Bear', 'Moon', 4),
('Peter', 'Saturn', 5),
('John Fox', 'Moon', 4),
('Micheal', 'Sun', 1),
('Jackie', 'Sun', 1),
('Tito', 'Sun', 1),
('Peter', 'Saturn', 5)
```

Get location and count

```
select Location_Name, count(1)
from 
(select Name, Location_Name,
   rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Location_ID ORDER BY Name)
   from People_Location
 ) t
 where rn = 1
group by  Location_Name
```

Result

```
Moon  2
Saturn 1
Sun  3
```

Answer (score 2):

Deleting duplicates is a common pattern. You apply a sequence number to all of the duplicates, then delete any that aren't first. In this case I order arbitrarily but you can choose to keep the one with the lowest PK value or that was modified last or whatever - just update the `ORDER BY` to sort the one you want to keep first.

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY Name, Location_ID ORDER BY @@SPID)
  FROM dbo.TableName
)
DELETE cte WHERE rn > 1;
```

Then to count, assuming there can't be two different `Location_ID`s for a given `Location_Name` (this is why schema + sample data is so helpful):

```
SELECT Location_Name, People = COUNT(Name)
  FROM dbo.TableName
  GROUP BY Location_Name;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=768987a62a28e2e6eac561df93790d9c)

If `Location_Name` and `Location_ID` are *not* tightly coupled (e.g. there could be `Location_ID = 4, Location_Name = Place 1` and `Location_ID = 4, Location_Name = Place 2` then you're going to have to define how to determine which place to display if you group by `Location_ID`, or admit that perhaps one of those columns is meaningless.

If `Location_Name` and `Location_ID` *are* tightly coupled, they shouldn't *both* be stored in this table. You should have a lookup/dimension table that stores both of those columns (once!) and you use the smallest data type as the key you record in the fact table (where it is repeated over and over again). This has several benefits:

- Scanning the bigger table is faster, because it's not as wide
- Storage is reduced because you're not repeating long strings over and over and over again
- Aggregation is clearer and you can join to get names *after* aggregation, which will be faster
- If you need to change a location's name, you only need to change it in exactly one place

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to learn SQL again and am having fun learning some stuff I never knew as well.

Comment: @Timothy See what I mean about branch name and branch key being tightly coupled? If branch key 6 is always Hawaii then it is redundant and wasteful (never mind problematic for potential updates) to store both 6 and Hawaii on every row. You should have a separate table like Branches that has key/name and you store 6 and Hawaii there. Then in this table from your screenshot, you don't need the branch name column.